# Managing events of filling select fields based on input fields

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic

im having a problem with dynamic forms.
I have dynamically created forms on button "add". forms have ids like "editForm_1".
for example, i have an input "Education_1" and the select box that will be filled on input click and options will be based on input value. having like 5 of those input fields and selects.
the thing is that how can i manage all those events? cause i dont think .each input is a good solution. 
thanks
UPD:

```
$("#education").delegate("input", "keypress", function(){
if($(this).val().length>1){
    var selector = $(this).next();
    selector.empty() ;                             
    var words = $(this).val();
    $.postJSON("2.php", words, function(data){
        var tmp = data; 
        $.each(tmp, function(i, val){
            var s=selector;
            s.options[s.options.length]= new Option(val.type, val.type);
        });
    });
}
```

});

But im getting "s.options is undefined" ERROR

got it, used 
s.append( new Option(val.type, val.type)); 
instead and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching events using their ID's, group the inputs into classes, then attache the event handler(s) using `.delegate` or `.on` for these classes.

e.g

```
<input id="Education_1" class="education" /> 
<input id="Education_2" class="education" />
```

The js

```
$(document).delegate('.education','click', function(){

});
```

Comment: i thought of this. so..
for example, having an input and select in a div "education":
`
$("#education").delegate("input", "keypress", function(){
 if($(this).val().length>1){
  //dont have a clue how to manage selector of select. can u help me? 
        }`

Comment: i mean the selector that corresponds to the first input.

Comment: You can just check `$(this).is(':select')` that will tell you if it's a select, if it's not then you know that that's an input.

Comment: but how can i find selectbox from $(this) using "parent(), next()" if its in the structure is like this.
<div>
<div>Учебное заведение:</div>
<input id="edNam1e_1" type="text" name="name">
</div>
<div>
<div></div>
<select id="edOpti1ons_1"></select>
</div>

Comment: sry, still confusing for me, can u help me?

`var selector = $(this).parent().next().children();`
`selector[1].append is not a function`
`selector[1].append( new Option(val.type, val.type));`